# How to add Dynamic Javascript to <a> tag in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I apply dynamic href attribute with JavaScript to anchore tag in MVC. My requirement is to open window on click of `<a>` . Opening window I need to pass certain parameters from controller side like URL or is user logged in or not etc. I have similar code developed in web forms like below in code behind

Code behind :

```
if (User!= null) {
                        AspHyperLink.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript: openWindows('" + anchoreLink.ClientID + "', '" + URL +
                                                                         "', null, 'width=952,height=600,left=25,top=50,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no', '" +
                                                                         guestUser.ToString().ToLower() + "','" + DelayTime + "','" + SomimageImage.ClientID + "','" +
                                                                         imgfadedPath + "','" + imgpath + "');");
```

How can i achieve this in MVC world ?

Comment: Some properties like ClientID, etc seems already available in model or route. So utilize those for populating them in the view. For others, consider using ViewBag or ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

Pass all parameter through model to your view and call a javascript method on onclick event of your anchor tag. If there are multiple such anchors then take proprieties in model otherwise you can use ViewBag.
Code will looks like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="OpenWindow('@Model.ClientID','@Model.URL','@Model.guestUser', '@Model.DelayTime',     '@Model.SomeimageClientId','@Model.imgfadedPath','@Model.imgpath')"> Click Here</a>



<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenWindow(ClientID,URL,guestUser, DelayTime, SomeimageClientId,imgfadedPath,imgpath)
{
      //Open Window Here.
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, your View populates any parameters needed by JavaScript. You controller should collect all the variables needed by the View (like clientId, imgpath, imgfadedPath, etc...) into a model (or if you're lazy, into ViewBag). Then, in the View, you can use these parameters to create the  tag:

Here's an example with the Razor view engine:

```
<a href="javascript: openWindows('@Model.clientId, @Model.URL, ....')">click here</a>
```